# Firebase update UI based on user answer after some time

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

So basically, there is 10 choices a user can make, and after one of them is selected (only one can be selected) a couple hours pass and that "question" gets a true or false answer meaning that neither me or the user knows beforehand what the answer will be

How would one go about keeping track of every user selection (if there are like 100 users) and after some time updating everything based on a random answer that question gets and updating users score as well

---

Here is the screenshot of the current DB:

[image]

Basically 10 matches all sorted like that, currently what I have up and running

Comment: Can you provide more details? Maybe share what your db looks like and some code that you've tried?

Comment: Hey Dharmaraj,

Currently I only have a Realtime DB that provides text for the "bets" people can make

So basically, if you ever heard of ESPN Streak, this would be pretty much the same idea

User bets on a game, after that game is finished I need to update it and everyone who selected that game should get an updated score as well

Comment: Sharing a screenshot of database structure and explaining helps :)

Comment: Here is the screenshot of the current DB https://snipboard.io/KeDAcP.jpg

Basically 10 matches all sorted like that, currently what I have up and running